# Ubuntu with plasma desktop has problems displaying applications properly

Tags: xubuntu, kubuntu, display

I really don't know why this occurs.

Zoom:
[image]

---

Teamviewer:
[image]

---

Konsole (weird white ugly lines)
[image]

Sometimes i get that anakondi or krunner crashed.

Is there something i can do to fix this? Please help.

**Update:**
Same issue on Ubuntu 20.04 after I did the update.

PS: I previously had XFCE installed on the same ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: @mook765 Ubuntu 19.10. It used to be Ubuntu 18 a long time ago tho. Some friend did the update, but this was almost a year ago.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is `End of Life` and not supported anymore. You should upgrade to a supported version ( 20.04 or 20.10) or reinstall older but still supported version of Ubuntu (16.04 or 18.04).

Comment: @mook765 how can I do that? do I have to download the OS again from the website. I have data on this laptop that i haven't backed up :/

Comment: Noboby prevents you from backing up your data first and I'd recommend to do so anyway. I'd also recommend to go the easy way and after you made your back-up, do a fresh install of 20.04 which has long term support, then copy your data back from your backup. [Difficult way](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/590937)...

Comment: @mook765 now the problem is I got no place where to backup data rn. I don't have an external drive atm. And putting it on smth like google drive would take a long time.

Comment: @mook765 same issue on ubuntu 20.04